# "hasPrefix" not working in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionary & I try to filter with prefix from using one of the key as follow:

```
let b = [["id":1,"name":"India"],["id":2,"name":"america"],["id":3,"name":"africa"],["id":4,"name":"indonesia"],["id":5,"name":"jakarta"],["id":6,"rec_name":"Zimba"]]

let g = b.filter({String(describing: $0["name"]).hasPrefix("I")})

print(g) //retun Empty array
```

**If I try with `contains` then it working fine**

or

**If I try with only pure String array then also  it working fine**

Thank you,

Comment: `String(describing:)` is almost *never* what you should use to "make something compile".

Comment: For something more complex than 1 line, dont try to shorten it so hard, will probably create problem, use if/guard let to proper check the value is better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your array (`b`) contains dictionaries where `name` is not always present (you have an object with `rec_name`), you could modify your filter to something like this:

```
let g = b.filter {
    guard let name = $0["name"] as? String else { return false }
    return name.hasPrefix("I")
}
```

and thus making sure that only dictionaries with a value for that key are matched by your filter

---

Fun fact: The reason why the original code doesn't work (as Martin points out) is pretty obvious when we do something like this:

```
let g = b.map({String(describing: $0["name"])}) 
print(g)
```

Which prints:

> ["Optional(\"India\")", "Optional(\"america\")", "Optional(\"africa\")", "Optional(\"indonesia\")", "Optional(\"jakarta\")", "nil"]

Comment: The dictionaries are of type `[String: Any]`, so the key might not only be absent but also its value might not be a string. Your filter already handles that but it might be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with this.

```
let b = [["id":1,"name":"India"],["id":2,"name":"america"],["id":3,"name":"africa"],["id":4,"name":"indonesia"],["id":5,"name":"jakarta"],["id":6,"rec_name":"Zimba"]]
let g = b.filter({String(describing: $0["name"] as? String ?? "").hasPrefix("I")})

print(g)
```

Comment: `String(describing:)` is not necessary. – Some explanations why the original code does not work would be useful, instead of a "code only" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you'll get the proper solution.

```
let b = [["id":1,"name":"India"],["id":2,"name":"america"], 
["id":3,"name":"africa"],["id":4,"name":"indonesia"],["id":5,"name":"jakarta"], 
["id":6,"rec_name":"Zimba"]]
let g = b.filter({($0["name"] as? String ?? "").hasPrefix("I")})
print(g)
```